# A seven letter word denoting a woman

Tags: word, wordplay

> I am a seven letter word.
>
> The first two letters denote men.
>
> The first three letters denote women.
>
> The first four letters denote men.
>
> The whole seven letters denote women.

**Who am I?**

Comment: You could take this further by stating what the first TWO letters denote.

Comment: And that the fifth letter could denote either.

Comment: I think i have seen the exact same question on the site before...

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The answer is

> Heroine

Explanation follows

> He - denotes men
> Her - denotes women
> Hero - denotes men
> Heroine - denotes women

Comment: The only part that could maybe be tweaked is the "first four letters denote men", but I was thinking the same thing.

Answer (score 7):

You are :

> Heroine, which refers to a woman

First two letters :

> He, which denotes a man

First three letters :

> Her, same

First four letters :

> Hero, refers to a man

Answer (score 6):

Here is another one.

> Evelina ("Evel" Knievel)

And another

> Hermine

And another

> Desiree

And another

> Shelley

There may be others of this form...

Comment: Nice, but the first one is eight letters, not seven.

Comment: Most of these don't make sense. What's a "herm" or a "hermine"? How do "Desi" and "shell" denote men? Of the two famous "Shelley"s, only one is a woman.

Comment: Herm denotes men, named Herm :P

Comment: @OrangeDog they are male and female names (admittedly most of them are fairly obscure)/

Answer (score 5):

A bit of a stretch at the end but..

First 3 letters:

> Her - denoting woman

First 4:

> Herr - The German equivalent of the 'Mr.' title

You are:

> HerRoom - An online lingerie retailer

Comment: That escalated quickly